# Merge 2+ USB tethering devices to share internet in eth0

Tags: networking, usb, internet, android, tethering

The picture below shows up the setup I would like to have:

[image: network diagram]

In summary, I have 2 Android devices with internet connections, and both are sharing their connection using Android USB tethering feature, then I want to merge both connections in Ubuntu notebook into a one single fast connection and after that, share this new merged connection through `eth0` (LAN) interface.

I've check some how-to to make a bonding in those connections into a `bond0` interface but I am not sure if this will work.
Once I need this bond0 interface to be my `eth0` sharing the internet access. Some IPTABLES maybe needed, but I does not know how to handle it.

I searched some old paid solutions for Windows, such as Speedfy/Connectify dispatcher, but I need to do this in Ubuntu and for free.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that the two cellular modems use regular consumer-grade cellular internet connections in which case **the short answer is no**.

#### Long answer: maybe (at additional cost)

The previous paragraph means that all outgoing packages are coerced to have the assigned source IP address *which differs for each connection*. IP link bonding is impossible without some device on the other end that can "un"-bond the incoming packages again to appear to come from the same source.

Some internet providers offer such services though usually targeted at business customers and they're priced accordingly. They may also offer other, more viable solutions to the same end. I recommend that you ask your internet provider about *generic* solutions to increase your (mobile) internet connection speed.

Comment: Dear David, thanks for you answer.
Let make me clarify the scenario.
I have 3 android phones with paid LTE connection, the contracted plan has inlimited GB data usage but the internet speed is limited to 7MB/s.
So, in order to speed-up my downloads, I'm wondering to merge those 3 android phones into a single connection (~21MB/s) then try to share this merged connection in eth0 interface to be used in a wifi router.
I hope this clarify my question and fell free to add something else.
Fernando.

Comment: @FernandoMineo: Could you please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. That being said, your additional info confirms the assumptions on which my answer is based and doesn't change it.

Comment: As you’ve never accepted an answer before: if this answers your question, don’t forget to click the grey ☑ under the number at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means “yes, this answer is valid”!